# Share buttons for different templates in ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have multiple models each of which has its own template. I want to share a footer of buttons accross the different templates so when the same button is pressed different functions are executed according to the selected template. The HTML looks like this:

```
    <script type="text/x-handlebars" id="application" >
       <menu>
          <nav>
             <ul>
               <li>{{#link-to 'model1'}}Model 1{{/link-to}}</li>
               <li>{{#link-to 'model2'}}Model 2{{/link-to}}</li>
               <li>{{#link-to 'model3'}}Model 3{{/link-to}}</li>
             </ul>
          </nav>
       </menu>

       <div class="content">
         <section>
           {{outlet}}
         </section>
       </div>

      <footer>
        <ul>
          <li><button class="action-undo" {{action undo}}>Undo</button></li>
          <li><button class="action-save" {{action save this}}>Save</button></li>
          <li><button class="action-saveContinue" {{action saveAndContinue this}}>Save & Continue</button></li>
        </ul>
      </footer>
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use the `{{partial}}` helper. It will inline a template (with the same context) when it is called.

To use the partial helper just create a template with a leading underscore, like :`_buttons`. To include that template you can now use `{{partial "buttons"}}`.

See: http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/rendering-with-helpers/

Comment: This works but the problem is that I would have to replicate the `<div class="content">` and `<section>` across multiple templates, including templates that are not for models. Is there any way to generalize that?

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the application template with the footer so all templates inserted in the outlet will have the footer.

To get the actions triggering to some corresponding template, just override the route of that template, for example in the `model1` template, you can create a `App.Model1Route` implementing the actions:

```
App.Model1Route = Ember.Route.extend({
    actions: {
        undo: function() {
            // perform undo
        },
        save: function() {
            // perform save
        },
        saveAndContinue: function() {
            // perform save and continue
        }
    }
});
```

And for `model2` template just override the `App.Model2Route` and add the actions to be triggered in that template, and so on.

Give a look in that fiddle to see this working http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/d3xA6/

Be careful because if some route don't implement some triggered action, an error is raised. In that case you can extract your footer to a `partial` and just add where is used.

I hope it helps

Comment: I thought the same but what if the actions need to take as a parameter the model that is passed to the outlet?

Comment: You will use that footer just to crud templates, not your entire app. Right?